# Javascript Event Handler Not Working React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create and render components depending on the value of the select option the user picks.
I am using template strings but i am having a problem with the event handler.
The Function Doesn't Trigger

Below Is My Code

```
const handleBooleanAnswerChoose = (event) =>{
 console.log(event.target)
}
 switch (question.answerType) {
    case "booleanChoices":
        const element = `<form id='booleanAnswerType' class='answerType'>
                         <label for='firstTrue' class='selectAnswerStyle'>
                         <input type='radio' onclick=${handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event)} id='firstTrue' name='booleanAnswer' value='True' />
                         </label>
                         <label for='firstFalse' class='selectAnswerStyle'>
                         <input type='radio' id='firstFalse' onclick=${handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event)} name='booleanAnswer' value='false' />
                          </label>
                    </form>`
                    parentToAppendTo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', element)
                    break;
                default:
                    return <div>Nunca</div>
```

After A Suggestion To Pass A Reference To The Event Handler

`onclick=${(event) =>handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event))}`

instead of

`onclick =${handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event)}`
The Result I Had On The Elements With The Event Handlers Are Below

[image]

Comment: Wait, why are you mixing `insertAdjacentHTML` and template strings with React and JSX..? Nothing good will likely come from that...

Comment: How Do You Suggest I Should Go About It Then ?

Comment: By just using React components, as one does. What are you _doing_ here in the grander scheme of things?  What is `parentToAppendTo`?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by writing a regular React component (functional or class-based), using JSX and rendering it in the DOM "the React way".

Then you need to pass a reference to the handler function, not calling it right away :

```
<input type='radio' onClick=${(event) => handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event)} id='firstTrue' name='booleanAnswer' value='True' />
```

`(event) => handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event)` instead of `handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event)`

You'll have to fix this on every element with an event handler.

You also need to use onClick instead of onclick (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

With your initial syntax, you assign the result of the handleBooleanAnswerChoose function evaluation (so a javascript value, wich is not a function) as the event handler, so this cannot work as expected (a value is not callable).

Comment: When I Do It This Way, In The DOM, The Raw Code Displays Instead Of The HTML ELEMENT.
I am going to update my question with the result i had from your solution

Comment: I just noticed an error on event handler : to capture click event, use onClick (not onclick). Added reference in my answer.

Comment: @FlorianMotteau OP is putting HTML in template strings, not using JSX – no `onClick` change will help there...

Comment: yes just noticed that...updated my answer, starting with that minor detail :).

Answer (score 0):

Well. The Above Approach I Used Earlier On Didn't Help Me.
I Figured Out How To Do It In A Different Way Using ReactDOM;

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
const parentToAppendTo = event.target.parentElement;
const element = <form id='booleanAnswerType' class='answerType'>
    <label for='firstTrue' class='selectAnswerStyle'>
        <input type='radio' onclick={(event)=>handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event)} id='firstTrue' name='booleanAnswer' value='True' />
    </label>
    <label for='firstFalse' class='selectAnswerStyle'>
        <input type='radio' id='firstFalse' onclick={(event)=>handleBooleanAnswerChoose(event)} name='booleanAnswer' value='false' />
    </label>
</form>

ReactDOM.render(element,parentToAppendTo);
```

## This Worked Perfectly For Me

Comment: This will mean you might have multiple or nested React roots within your app, which may cause problems further on. Most (but not all) React apps will have only one `ReactDOM.render` call.